# Add a moving star to the border of a paragraph

Tags: html, css

**how to add a *moving star* to the *border* of a paragraph**

```
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
   #p1
   {
    border-image:
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="p1"> 
    paragraph 
 </p>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "moving star"?

Comment: Are you talking about positioning an animated gif or something like CSS3 animations?

Comment: Please specify what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should show the url of the image in this case your star in the css. like so

```
#p1{
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 5 */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;

}
```

here is a [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image).

Comment: Highly doubt that's what 's asked

Comment: That's stars (plural) and they're not moving!

Comment: [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/)